# Can't use the wireless internet on Zorin OS and Fedora

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers, zorin

This question is not just depended on Zorin OS distribution.

I can't use the wireless internet. When I opened the program called 'Device Manager' on Windows, my network adapter was 'Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter', and there was 'Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller' too. (My computer is HP Probook 470)

I tried other Debian-based distros, but I failed.

I can't find the wireless internet. Ethernet works. But my room's structure is not good for connecting to the Ethernet.

What should I try?

**Update**:

```
09:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
```

Comment: Type : `lspci -vnn | grep Network`  and give the output

Comment: @GAD3R I added to the question.

Comment: Have you considered buying a longer ethernet cable (and hiding it behind furniture etc wherever possible)?  Don't forget to use duct tape or similar if the cable needs to cross a doorway or other high-traffic area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`
Type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

If you have an error, Try to install `linux-headers` and `build essential`:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

**FEDORA**

Install the RPM Fusion repositories.
[rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration)

Determine the architecture of the running kernel.

```
uname -r
```

Do this step only if you need to install the kmod version of the driver for the i686 or x86_64 kernels.

```
 su
 yum install kmod-wl
```

Do this step only if you need to install the `kmod` version of the driver for the PAE kernel.

```
 su
 yum install kmod-wl-PAE
```

Do this step only if you want to install the `akmod` version of the driver for any kernel.

```
su
yum install akmod-wl
```

Now reboot or restart NetworkManager and look in the NetworkManager panel icon for available networks (left-click the icon)

Some things to try if it doesn't work

Check the installed packages against the running kernel. It should all make sense by the version numbers. If it doesn't, then fix the installed packages situation. And make sure the correct kernel is running for the installed `kmod` package versions

```
uname -r
rpm -qa | grep -e kernel -e broadcom-wl -e kmod-wl | sort
```

Check the loaded kernel modules. The `wl` module should be loaded, and potentially conflicting modules such as `b43`, b43legacy, and `ssb` should not be loaded.

```
lsmod | sort
```

If wl is not loaded, then try manually loading it.

```
 su
 modprobe wl
 service NetworkManager restart
```

If manually loading the module worked, then add that `modprobe` command to `/etc/rc.local`.

```
su
echo "modprobe wl" >> /etc/rc.local
```

If a conflicting module is being loaded, then blacklist the unwanted module. Examples:

```
su
echo "blacklist b43" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I get the Answer from `fedoraforum.org`

Comment: Thank you so much. What was the problem? What is bcmwl-kernel-source?

Comment: `bcmwl` = Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source

Comment: How can I install this on Fedora?